# Nginx cache hit with long $request_time

Tags: nginx

`$upstream_cache_status` is HIT, but the `$request_time` sometimes last for 5s, What's the problem?

My nginx.conf

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    client_max_body_size 30M;

    proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp_dir;
    proxy_cache_path /tmp/proxy_cache_dir levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache:500m inactive=1d max_size=500m;

    log_format cache_log '$remote_addr - [$request_time] $status $upstream_cache_status "$request"';

    server {
        access_log  logs/access.log cache_log;
        error_log   logs/error.log error;

        proxy_cache cache;
        proxy_cache_valid 10m;

        location / {
            proxy_next_upstream http_502 error timeout;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_pass http://xxxxxx;
        }
    }

    include /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/vhosts/*.conf;
}
```

And access.log:

```
x.x.x.x - [5.076] 200 HIT "GET /xxx"
x.x.x.x - [0.092] 200 HIT "GET /xxx"
```

Same request url, both are hit the cache, why `$request_time` last for 5s or more?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it always the first hit? I would say the called element is not cached.

Comment: Log `$upstream_response_time`. Is it first request to that url for a long time? Could it be HDD delay?

Comment: @AlexeyTen All HIT request's $upstream_response_time is null.

Comment: @Otanaught not the first hit.

Comment: I can't think of anything other than slow disk read.

Comment: @Thanks for your help, I will test it on SSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a disk IO problem, I moved the proxy_cache_path to another SSD and the problem is solved.